# Uncaught TypeError Property $ of object[object Object] is not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to use this piece of code to provide a carousel based on jquery.carousel-main.min.js in my Wordpress site. But the script is throwing an uncaught error at $window.load(function).

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    function loadSlider(){

        // --------------------------- Configure Variables --------------------------- //

        // Set max slides to 1 if smartphone or 1 if not
        if (!($('.content-width').css('width') == '960px' || $('.content-width').css('width') == '720px')) { var var_minslides = 1; var var_maxslides = 1; } else { var var_minslides = 5; var var_maxslides = 5; };

        // Set slide width depending on resolution
        if (!($('.content-width').css('width') == '960px' || $('.content-width').css('width') == '720px')) { var var_slidewidth = 0; };
        if ($('.content-width').css('width') == '720px') { var var_slidewidth = 144; };
        if ($('.content-width').css('width') == '960px') { var var_slidewidth = 192; };

        // --------------------------- Slider Settings --------------------------- //
        sliderSettings = {
            minSlides: var_minslides,
            maxSlides: var_maxslides,
            moveSlides: 1,
            pager: false,
            responsive: false,
            useCSS: true,
            hideControlOnEnd: true,
            touchEnabled: true,
            infiniteLoop: true,
            auto: true,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
            slideWidth: var_slidewidth,
            nextSelector: '#clients-next', // Next slide link
            prevSelector: '#clients-back' // Previous slide link
        }

        clients_slider = $('#clients-carousel').bxSlider_content(sliderSettings);

    };

    // --------------------------- Load Slider --------------------------- //
    loadSlider();

    // ---------------------------  Reload Slider on Resize --------------------------- //
    $(window).resize(function(){
        clients_slider.destroySlider();
        loadSlider();
    });
});
```

Comment: You have JS dependency issues... jQuery core should always be the first script included on a page.

Comment: also its a bad idea to leak to `window`.

Comment: Thanks for replying jQuery is being loaded by wordpress. Instead of window should I be using document.ready

Comment: are you sure your bxSlider plugin is included?

Comment: Yes I have included the jquery.carousel-main.min.js file in header.php

Comment: Check javascript console there may be other issues or wrap your code with IIFE `(function ($, undefined) { /* your code */ }(jQuery));`

Comment: it's definitely conflicting with jQuery because when I change the top line to this. jQuery(window).load{function($){ the original error is gone but throws a new one on at this line if (!($('.content-width').css('width') == '960px' || $('.content-width').css('width') == '720px')) { var var_minslides = 1; var var_maxslides = 1; } else { var var_minslides = 5; var var_maxslides = 5; }; the error is uncaught TypeError object is not a function